# how to solve Trying to get property 'sub_cat_name' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

By using view composer to pass variables i got the error like this:

> "Trying to get property 'sub_cat_name' of non-object (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\E-commerce\resources\views\layouts\includes\top.blade.php)". please resolve the proble the code is given below:

AppServiceProvider:

```
View::composer(['layouts.includes.top'], function ($view) {
    $view->with('subcat', SubCategory::get());
});
```

controller:

```
public function prdtview()
{

    $categories = Category::get();
    $data=DB::select('select category.cat_name,product_images.prdt_image,product.prdt_name,product.actual_price from product INNER JOIN category on product.catid = category.id INNER JOIN product_images on product.id = product_images.prdt_id where product.sub_cat_id = 3 ');

        return view("frontend.product",[
        'data' => $data,
        'category' =>$categories
    ]);
}
```

blade file:

```
 <div class="nav-item">
        <div class="container">
            <nav class="nav-menu mobile-menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a></li>
                    @foreach($category as $category)
                        <li><a href="#">{{$category->cat_name}}</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            @foreach($subcat as $subcat)
                            <li><a href="#"><?php echo $subcat->sub_cat_name; ?></a></li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    @endforeach                        
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div id="mobile-menu-wrap"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Post your category model definition

Comment: it is good to keep the entity which is to be iterated different from its each component, you can use plurals eg foreach($categories as $category)

Comment: class Category extends Model
{
     use SoftDeletes;

     protected $table = 'category';
     protected $primaryKey = 'id';

     public $timestamps = true;

     protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
}

Comment: in your controller show dd($categories->toArray());

Comment: @bhucho same error..

Comment: I am telling write `dd($categories->toArray());` below `$categories = Category::get();` in your controller, show the output in the question by editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it:

```
@foreach($subcat as $subcat)
      <li><a href="#"><?php echo $subcat->sub_cat_name; ?></a></li>
@endforeach
```

to some thing like :

```
 @foreach($subcat as $sub_cat)
     <li><a href="#"><?php echo $sub_cat->sub_cat_name; ?></a></li>
 @endforeach
```